# Documentation for javascript audio methods?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, methods

I've searched and found many articles that discuss the common methods you can use in javascript to control HTML audio elements. However, I have not been able to find anywhere that lists all of the methods available.

I should make it clear that I'm not looking for HTML audio attributes. I'm looking for methods like `audio.play()` and `audio.pause()`. I've seen these methods used in code samples all over the place, but I can't find an exhaustive list for the life of me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're looking for something more generic: HTMLMediaElement, here are some reference guides:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLMediaElement

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#audio

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/htmlmediaelement

Comment: Yes! The first and third links are exactly what I was looking for. Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

For Mozilla Firefox's implementation (Gecko), see the following in the Mozilla Development Center:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Audio
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLAudioElement
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introducing_the_Audio_API_Extension

For Internet Explorer 9 (currently beta), see the following at MSDN:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975061.aspx

Comment: I've seen those pages on MDC, however none of them provide any information about methods (unless I'm totally missing something). The MSDN page is exactly what I'm looking for, except (shockingly) I don't care about IE for this project.

Comment: and @Bryan: As both HTMLVideoElement and HTMLAudioElement share many of the same methods, they're inherited from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLMediaElement, which has most of the methods.

Answer (score 4):

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html#audio (large document)

The play/pause methods can be found here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html#media-element

Comment: First link is broken... is [this](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#the-audio-element) what you had originally intended to link?