# Play music from a specific point

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-cookie, background-music

Is it possible to set the starting time of some background music on a site ? My code is below.

```
//Head
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var bgMusic = $('#audio-bg')[0],
            playing = true;
        var $volume_btn = $('#toggle');

        bgMusic.addEventListener('ended', function() {
            this.currentTime = 10;
            if (playing) {
                this.play();
            }
        }, false);

        var cookieValue = $.cookie("forcemute");

        if(cookieValue == undefined){
            bgMusic.play();
        }
        else{
            playing = false;
            $volume_btn.css({backgroundPosition: '0 -21px'});
        }

        $volume_btn.click(function() {
            if (!bgMusic.paused) {
                bgMusic.pause();
                playing = false;
                $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '0 -21px'})

                $.cookie("forcemute", 1);
            } else {
                bgMusic.play();
                playing = true;
                $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '0 0'})

                $.removeCookie("forcemute");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

//Body
<audio id="audio-bg">
                <source src="music/Something_for_Nothing_OST_-_Close_darkness_The.mp3">Update your browser for playing music</source>
            </audio>
            <a id="toggle" class="volume-icon" href="javascript:"></a>
```

Is it possible to set a cookie with the current time of the music, and on change/refresh page continue to play music from the time which is in the cookie?

For example I would load my site, and music plays for 15 seconds before I change to another page within my site. Instead of playing the music from the start, can I get a value from a cookie from previous page and continue playing from that time?

Maybe there is some method to get the current time of the music, and then play from that point?

Comment: from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4589616/2375207 you may lurk in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement and consider setting "currentTime"

Comment: But maybe there is a way to get current music time ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement : currentTime : The current playback time, in seconds. Setting this value seeks the media to the new time.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution.

I can update the cookie variable every 2000ms, and check if cookieStartTime isset, then continue playing music or start from beginning.

Below is my full code.

```
$(function() {
        var bgMusic = $('#audio-bg')[0],
            playing = true;
        var $volume_btn = $('#toggle');
        var cookieMute = $.cookie("forcemute");
        var cookieStartTime = $.cookie("time");

        bgMusic.addEventListener('ended', function() {
            this.currentTime = 0;
            if (playing) {
                this.play();
            }
        }, false);

        setInterval(function() {
            $.cookie('time', bgMusic.currentTime);
        }, 2000);

        if(cookieStartTime == undefined){
            $('audio').bind('canplay', function(){
                $(this)[0].currentTime = 0;
            });
        }
        else {
            $('audio').bind('canplay', function(){
                $(this)[0].currentTime = cookieStartTime;
            });
        }

        if(cookieMute == undefined){
            bgMusic.play();
        }
        else {
            playing = false;
            $volume_btn.css({backgroundPosition: '0 -20px'});
        }

        $volume_btn.click(function() {
            if (!bgMusic.paused) {
                bgMusic.pause();
                playing = false;
                $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '0 -20px'})
                $.cookie("forcemute", 1);
            } else {
                bgMusic.play();
                playing = true;
                $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '0 -2px'})

                $.removeCookie("forcemute");
            }
        });
    });
```