# javascript: play files from google drive

Tags: javascript

I have a website and need to play an audio file with JavaScript using

```
var audio = new Audio(file);
audio.play();
```

Unfortunatly, the **web-space hos**t doesn't allow to upload mp3 files.
Can I play a file stored at my google drive account somehow

Comment: I think you have probably missed this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589451/documentation-for-javascript-audio-methods

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with **HTML5** you can use [Direct Link Creator](http://directlink.booogle.net/) plugin of Google Drive and get the link easily. Here's an example.

```
<audio controls="controls">
    <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_ETxiqrp0SzbF9VQ3JCS2hnSlU">
</audio>

<video controls="controls">
    <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B0JMGMGgxp9WMEdWb1hyQUhlOWs" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

If you don't want to mess with HTML elements:

```js
var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
audio.play();
```

This uses the [`HTMLAudioElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) interface, which plays audio the same way as the [`<audio>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio).

If you need more functionality, use the [howler.js](http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library) library and found it simple and useful.